# LAN to PPTP VPN bridge

Tags: vpn, local-area-network, pptp, tomato

I am pretty new to VPN and networking stuff so please bear with me if this seems a noob question. I have a cisco linksys e2500 router running on Tomato firmware.

My situation is, I have set up a PPTP VPN server on the router and I am able to connect to the VPN from multiple remote machines and each of these machines can ping and ssh into each other. I also have a couple of Linux machines connected to the same router via ethernet and are not part pf the VPN. What I want is to be able to access and ssh/telnet into these Linux machines via the remote machines that are connected to the VPN server. The Linux host machines cannot be configured to install the VPN client due to memory limitations (they are a pair of acoustic modems).

If someone can give me some pointers on if and how can this be done, it would be really helpful for me.